# Commuting operators in polar decomposition of normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $f$ be a normal operator on $V$. Let $f=PU$ be polar decomposition of $f$, where $P$-nonnegative, self-adjoint and $U$ - unitary(orthogonal) operator. Prove that $PU=UP$.

**My attempt:** Since $f$ is normal then $ff^*=f^*f$ and $f^*=U^*P$ then $ff^*=PUU^*P=P^2$ and $f^*f=U^*PPU=U^*P^2U.$ Combining them we get that $$P^2=U^*P^2U \Leftrightarrow UP^2=P^2U$$

I don't know what to do next.

Can anyone show how to prove this, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did most of the work. Because $P^2 = U^*P^2U$ and non-negative operators have unique non-negative square roots, we can conclude that $P = U^*PU \iff UP = PU$.

Equivalently, we could use the fact that there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ for which $g(P^2) = P$.

Comment: Every time I am very close to the solution but never can solve it :)  To be honest I did not get how did you get that $g(P^2)=P$?

Comment: @ZFR Either this fact or the uniqueness of square roots is usually proven as a theorem in textbooks/notes. It's non-trivial; the usual proof uses the spectral theorem

Comment: Let me ask you the question regarding the first paragraph of your answer: So we know that $P^2=(U^*PU)^2=U^*P^2U$. And we see that $U^*P^2U$ is self-adjoint and non-negative. I know that it has unique self-adjoint non-negative square root. Also $P$ is self-adjoint and non-negative. We have to show that $U^*PU$ is self-adjoint and non-negative. Self-adjointness is very obvious. But non-negativity is not. We have to consider $(U^*PU(x),x)=(PU(x),U(x))$

Comment: @ZFR Taking $y = U(x)$, we see that $(PU(x),U(x)) = (Py,y)$. Because $P$ is non-negative, $(P(y),y) \geq 0$.

Comment: Ohh god! I am so stupid. Thanks a lot! I did not notice this triviality at all!